# Scala - null (?) as default value for named Int parameter

Tags: scala, parameters, null, named

I'd like to do in Scala something I would do in Java like this:

```
public void recv(String from) {
    recv(from, null);
}
public void recv(String from, Integer key) {
    /* if key defined do some preliminary work */
    /* do real work */
}

// case 1
recv("/x/y/z");
// case 2
recv("/x/y/z", 1);
```

In Scala I could do:

```
def recv(from: String,
         key: Int = null.asInstanceOf[Int]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

but it looks ugly. Or I could do:

```
def recv(from: String,
         key: Option[Int] = None) {
    /* ... */
}
```

but now call with key looks ugly:

```
// case 2
recv("/x/y/z", Some(1));
```

What's the proper *Scala way*? Thank you.

Comment: what about default value = -1 or 0?

Comment: @Antoras That's possible, but not elegant (suppose that key can be any Int value).

Comment: "Some" will cease to look ugly once it saves you from a few dozen NullPointerExceptions :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Option` way is the Scala way. You can make the user code a little nicer by providing helper methods.

```
private def recv(from: String, key: Option[Int]) {
  /* ... */
}

def recv(from: String, key: Int) {
  recv(from, Some(key))
}

def recv(from: String) {
  recv(from, None)
}
```

`null.asInstanceOf[Int]` evaluates to `0` by the way.

Comment: Hmm, I would have just put the OP's `/*do some preliminary work*/` in the two method overload, and then had that call the one method overload which does the `/*do real work*/`?  Is the use of `Option` more idiomatic Scala?

Comment: @TimGoodman, "then had that call the one method overload" -- with what argument?

Comment: With the string `from` that was passed to the two-method overload

Answer (score 3):

`Option` really does sound like the right solution to your problem - you really do want to have an "optional" `Int`.

If you're worried about callers having to use `Some`, why not:

```
def recv(from: String) {
  recv(from, None)
}

def recv(from: String, key: Int) {
  recv(from, Some(key))
}

def recv(from: String, key: Option[Int]) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is, of course, to use `Option`. If you have problems with how it looks, you can always resort to what you did in Java: use `java.lang.Integer`.